# Angular 8. How can I Click Login button on login page, and display the user name on Navbar component in next page?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular8

My page has 3 components, the Navbar component the menu component and the login component.
The app.component.html looks like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The login and menu component will be rendered in "router-outlet", the Navbar will be rendered in "app-navbar". 
When I typed in user name and password and click submit button, if login successful, I will router the "router-outlet" from Login component to Menu component.
My desire is when Menu component shows up, I will see user first name and last name on the Navbar, under the title at the center of the new line. Something like this:

[image]

This is the HTML for Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar rf-scanner-navbar">
  <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div *ngIf="currentUserInfo" class="row">
    <p class="userInfo">{{currentUserInfo.firstname}} {{currentUserInfo.lastname}}</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The problem is, I need to refresh the whole page to force the the Navbar to reload to display the name. Is that anyway I can do to make the Navbar component able to detect the data changed and display it?

This is the ts code for the Navebar Component, I injected the injectable authService file, which will call a Api to get user info:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'hello-world';
  currentUserInfo = this.authService.currentUserValue;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I also have this public method in auth service file:

```
  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
```

One more question, how to make the name Div at the center of a new line under the title("hello-world")?So far they are at the same line, the 
 doesn't work, I photo shopped the picture above.

Let me know if you need more information about this.

Comment: You should put the line `currentUserInfo = this.authService.currentUserValue;` in `ngOnInit`. In principal, you should put all initialization that uses some injected service into `ngOnInit`.

Comment: What is the type of `this.currentUserSubject`?

Comment: BehaviorSubject, I tried the oninit way, it doesn't work, I still need to refresh to get it display

Comment: Yeah, I didn't expect it to fix this issue, but it's a good practice for future usage. Otherwise you may get really weird bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use authService  property directly:

```
<div *ngIf="authService.currentUserValue" class="row">
    <p class="userInfo">{{authService.currentUserValue.firstname}} {{authService.currentUserValue.lastname}}</p>
  </div>
```

The value will update as the service value does.

To centre the div on a new line, try moving it to just below the h1 tag:

```
<nav class="navbar rf-scanner-navbar">
  <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <div *ngIf="currentUserInfo" class="row">
      <p class="userInfo">{{currentUserInfo.firstname}} 
        {{currentUserInfo.lastname}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Put 'text-align: center' on the class / style.

Comment: I do have the injectable service, please see edited question above. Thank you for answering.

Comment: So you can use {{authService.currentUserValue.firstName}} in your html i.e. using your authService property directly instead of assigning it to the currentUserInfo property. Amended answer.

Comment: It worked :). I fking love you bro. I am very new to front-end development, you have no idea how much you helped me... btw, the name still is showing next to the title not the next new line...any idea?

Comment: :) Injected services are one of the great things about Angular, have a read up on it on Angular site. Depends on other styles and their effect. Try removing "row" class temporarily to see if it helps. Or setting "clear:both" on the div. Hard to say for me without seeing all the css.

Comment: I removed d-sm-flex and row,userInfo. It works now :) Thx bro!

Comment: I don't think this is very good practice, since `currentUserValue` will be called multiple times by the Angular change detection. A better solution would be to expose the BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it in `ngOnInit`